# How to get android app detail using package name

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

I have some android package names that look like the below:

1. com.sampleandroidapp.android

What do I want:

I need a **free** API or site to give android package name and get app detail

***By the way I need a free one because I am working on a small project***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, after researching several days, I think there isn't any free API to get android app details but I found an API that called AppBrain.
after signing up you can use this API and 500 requests to get app details.
https://www.appbrain.com/